Do pawns take their inventory with them when they leave your party?
As I have been exploring the countryside I often bump into pawns who would like to join my party. Sometimes they are higher level than the folks already accompanying me, so I tend to add them and dismiss the lower level pawns.
However it has only just occurred to me that some pawns tend to go off and pickup items and collect materials, so will have useful items in their backpack.
So if I dismiss them do I lose access to their inventory? Have I been inadvertently losing helpful materials, items and equipment?

Oh, if this is a thing, it will make Dragon Plague even more of a trash gimmik than it already is.

It seems that they do not take items away with them.
Reading this article from ScreenRant, they suggest that pawn inventories either go into the players bag, or to your storage at an Inn.

If a Pawn is dismissed or dies in Dragon's Dogma 2, anything they have in their inventory will simply appear in the player's storage, which can be accessed at any of the game's multiple inns. All a player needs to do is speak with the innkeeper and retrieve anything they've lost.

This was also confirmed with in-game testing by this article from Destructoid where they do also make a note about already having 99 of an item

if a stack in your storage is already at maximum (99), what happens to it? For me, I had over 99 goblin horns, so I gave a Pawn two of them and dismissed them. I checked my inventory, and they hadn’t returned. I then checked my storage, and they weren’t there either. I was also not financially reimbursed for them. The horns were simply gone.

